# Find CSS difference from two give links

Tags: html, css

What would be the easiest way to find a difference between two compacted css files. This can't be done at the server side using a diff tool since the final css comes from lots of sources.

Is there way to do something similar from the html of a webpage as well??

Comment: <p class="bold">Hello <p>

if the class bold changes i that could affect the way look and feel of the html i would like to detect

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this myself but might give this a try
http://gordianlabs.com/cssdiff/index.htm